# heroku mongo console login:-

Tags: mongodb, heroku

```
mongo paulo.mongohq.com:10061/app18111392 -u <user> -p<password>
```

The above is the documentation for login to heroku mongo HQ db

The username is:  sangram
the password is :  singh

when i type

```
mongo paulo.mongohq.com:10061/app18111392 -u sangram -p singh
```

i get the following error:-

```
04.316 JavaScript execution failed: Error: 18 { code: 18, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth fails" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:L228
```

What am i doing wrong?

PS:- i am performing it from terminal console on my mac.

Comment: those are not my real credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo mongo paulo.mongohq.com:10061/app18111392 -u sangram -p singh
```

followed by password (of my mac) worked.

Comment: Can you comment on https://github.com/Empeeric/heroku-mongo. does it work on Mac? does it require su privileges?