# Connect to heroku apps mongodb (compose) on terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, heroku

I have inherited a Ruby on rails app, which runs on Heroku and has a compose mongoDB. To be clear I have never used ruby, mongo or Heroku and its been a massive learning curve.

I essentially want to get a copy running locally, but more importantly I want to pull down and export the data that is in the db at the moment.

I have installed the latest version of Heroku Toolbelt and I have installed the latest version on mongodb, which also included all 4 packages. Im running this locally on Ubuntu 14 lts.

The documentation I do have says to run this command to log into the db

> mongodb://heroku:password-string@tempest.mongohq.com:10098/appid

But if I run just the above it says no such file or directory, if I add 'mongo' onto the beginning then it seems to work but throws the following error

> E QUERY    Error: More than one ':' detected. If this is an ipv6 address, it needs to be surrounded by '[' and ']'; heroku:password-string@tempest.mongohq.com:10098

I did try running it wrapped in [] too.

This is just getting in so I can then export the data locally and then try to look at it.

Comment: Could you add a link to the documentation? Maybe try without "heroku:"

Comment: The documentation was an email from the original builders which literlly was just a few lines. Im wondering if I should just ignore that and try to connect a different way! Using the Compose documentation now.

Comment: Can you connect with the solution of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807129/heroku-mongo-console-login?

Answer (score 0):

The command-line `mongo` tool doesn't understand URLs, so try this instead:

```
mongo -u heroku -p password-string tempest.mongohq.com:10098/appid
```

Also I'm pretty sure you can leave off the `-p password-string` and it will prompt you for it, so you can avoid revealing it in `ps` output etc.